# Listing Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

**Context**

I'm using python 3.8 and I'm having trouble with nested dictionaries. Every time I make a call to pull values from an endpoint, the names of the nested dictionaries change. I know how to pull the values I need out of the dictionary, but only if I know the names of the dictionaries ahead of time.

**Question**

How would I go about assigning the dictionary name to the variable? i.e, how would I go about creating a `variable = "ABCD-EFGH"` once I pulled the below result?

**Example structure of the nested dictionary:**

```
"result": {
        "ABCD-EFGH": {
            "Key1": "Value1",
            "Key2": "Value2",
        },
        "IJKL-MNOP": {
            "Key1": "Value1",
            "Key2": "Value2",
        },
     }
```

Comment: Still do not get your question?! It seems that you have a JSON file. Do you want to convert it to a dictionary and access the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Defining the dictionary:

```
dict = {"result":{"ABCD-EFGH":{"Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2"}, "IJKL-MNOP":{"Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2",},}}
```

If you want to look at the keys nested inside "result":

```
dict['result'].keys()
>>>dict_keys(['ABCD-EFGH', 'IJKL-MNOP'])
```

If you then want to extract these keys and store them in an array (use array comprehension). You can then store the first key as a variable like you asked:

```
res = [key for key in dict['result'].keys()]
mykey = res[0]
print(res)
>>>['ABCD-EFGH', 'IJKL-MNOP']
print(mykey)
>>>'ABCD-EFGH'
```

Lastly, if you want to grab a specific entry from the dictionary (say, the value corresponding to a specific set of keys:

```
dict['result']['ABCD-EFGH']['Key1']
>>>'Value1'
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this comment helped, could you please select it as the "accepted answer"? Thanks.